# How to make two manytomany fields in a model hold different values

Tags: django, django-models

I have Two simplified models as bellow:

```
class Courses:
    name = models.CharField(_("Course name"), max_length=256)


class School:
    main_courses = models.ManyToManyField(_("Main Courses"), to="course.Courses", related_name="maincourses", blank=True)
    enhancement_courses = models.ManyToManyField(_("Enhancement Courses"), to="course.Courses" related_name="enhancementcourses", blank=True)

    def clean(self) -> None:
      #check if selected items in main_courses and enhancement_courses are not equal
      status = [True for course in self.main_courses.all() if course in self.enhancement_courses.all()]
      if any(status):
          raise ValidationError("Chosen contents should not be equal")
      return None
```

`main_courses` and `enhancement_courses` are going to hold a list of Courses. But I need to make sure their values wont be equal. For example if in school_1, `main_courses` are math, physics then `enhancement_courses` can't be these values. What is the simplest way in django to do this?

**Update**

I need to validate when user select items in the fields `main_courses` and `enhancement_courses` in `School` table, after saving the changes, model should verify the chosen items in those two fields are not equal. At the moment, there is a bug in `clean()` method that it keeps the values of first validation/save. For example it raises error if `main_courses` and `enhancement_courses`chosen items are equal, but after deselecting, again it raises error.

Comment: Update question with your view

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize [ManyToMany.limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.limit_choices_to) to constrain only certain items for each field:

```py
class CourseCategory(models.TextChoices):
    MAIN = "main", "Main"
    ENHANCHEMENT = "enhancement", "Enhancement"

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Course name"), max_length=256)
    category = models.CharField(_("Course Category"), max_length=32, choices=CourseCategory.choices)


class School(models.Model):
    main_courses = models.ManyToManyField(_("Main Courses"), to="course.Courses", related_name="maincourses", blank=True, limit_choices_to=Q(category=CourseCategory.MAIN))
    enhancement_courses = models.ManyToManyField(_("Enhancement Courses"), to="course.Courses" related_name="enhancementcourses", blank=True, limit_choices_to=Q(category=CourseCategory.ENHANCEMENT))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But does this solution validates if each school has not equal MainCourses and EnhancementCourses?

Comment: I miss understood your question, changed my answer. Hopefully this is what you've meant

Comment: My solution was adding `def clean(self)` method to `School`. My only problem with my solution is validation works only once and them doesn't work, I updated my question with my solution.

Comment: I put your solution, while it's a good solution but it's not what I need. I don't want to limit Course items based on `main_courses` and `enhancement_courses`. I just need to validate the `School` fields `main_courses` and `enhancement_courses`, as described in the update.

Comment: Your question is not clear, please provide your view and an example

Comment: I don't have any view yet. My issue is in admin part, when admin wants to add a new record to School model, he/she will select Course items listed in `main_courses` and `enhancement_courses`. But all I need that my model to consider is that, when admin press the save button, if Course selected items in the above two fields are equal, django should raises error.(This should be called validation, right?). In other words, admin is not allowed to select equal items in those two fields